# Subset pandas dataframe by overlap with another

Tags: python, pandas

For the following two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': pd.Series(["A", "B", "C"]), 'value': pd.Series([1., 2., 3.])})

     name  value
0    A    1.0
1    B    2.0
2    C    3.0

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': pd.Series(["A", "C", "D"]), 'value': pd.Series([1., 3., 5.])})

     name  value
0    A    1.0
1    C    3.0
2    D    5.0
```

I would like to keep only the rows in `df2` where the value in the `name` column overlaps with a value in the `name` column of `df1`, i.e. produce the following dataframe:

```
     name  value
0    A    1.0
1    C    3.0
```

I have tried a number of approaches but I am new to python and pandas and don't appreciate the syntax coming from R. Why does this line of code not work, and what would?

```
df2[df2["name"] in df1["name"]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print (df2[df2["name"].isin(df1["name"])])
  name  value
0    A    1.0
1    C    3.0
```

Another faster solution with [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html):

```
val = np.intersect1d(df2["name"], df1["name"])
print (val)
['A' 'C']

print (df2[df2.name.isin(val)])
  name  value
0    A    1.0
1    C    3.0
```

Comment: I believe this doesn't work if the index is different.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different method that might be useful on your actual data, you could use an "inner join" (the intersection) a la SQL. More useful if your columns aren't duplicated in both data frames (e.g. merging two different data sets with some common key)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': pd.Series(["A", "B", "C"]), 'value': pd.Series([1., 2., 3.])})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': pd.Series(["A", "C", "D"]), 'value': pd.Series([1., 3., 5.])})

# supposedly for the join you should be able to tell join on='<column_name>', 'name' here, 
# but wasn't working for me.
df1.set_index('name', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('name', inplace=True)

df1.join(df2, how='inner', rsuffix='_other')

#       value  value_other
# name                    
# A       1.0          1.0
# C       3.0          3.0
```

Changing `how` to `outer` would give you the intersection of the two, `left` for just `df1` rows, `right` for `df2`.